# Second signer does not see signature placeholder

Tags: e-signature

There is a multi-age MD Word document that contains two anchors for two signers.
The anchors do not contains any spaces (i verified in underlying XML).

When I send a call to create an envelope, both are present and defined:

```json
{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [{
      "clientUserId": "29",
      "email": "signer@example.com",
      "name": "Signer Dude",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "tabs": {
        "signHereTabs": [{
          "anchorString": "SpeakerSignHere",
          "anchorUnits": "pixels",
          "anchorXOffset": "0",
          "anchorYOffset": "0",
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "clientUserId": "28",
      "email": "counter@example.com",
      "name": "John Smith",
      "recipientId": "2",
      "routingOrder": "2",
      "tabs": {
        "sign_here_tabs": [{
          "anchorString": "CounterSignHere",
          "anchorUnits": "pixels",
          "anchorXOffset": "0",
          "anchorYOffset": "0",
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

The first signer sees the signature field; the second - doesn't.

The second signer just shows the tool panel where they can set their signature anywhere.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The second tab was not properly named. `sign_here_tabs` instead of `signHereTabs`.